# NG-ZORRO Tree component with dropdowns instead of checkboxes?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I'm trying to create a tree using a tree component from ng-zorro but instead of checkboxes for the leaves I want to have dropdowns. I tried using the ng-template but the checkbox is still rendered. This is my code:

- Tree object:

```js
export let objectModel2: NzTreeNodeOptions[] = 
[
    {
        title: 'Test',
        key: '1',
        children: [
          {
            title: 'T1',
            key: '1.1',
            isLeaf: true      
          },
          {
            title: 'T2',
            key: '1.2',
            isLeaf: true
          }
        ]
    },
]
```

- HTML:

```html
<nz-tabset nzType="card">
        <nz-tree  nzCheckable [nzData]="objectModel2">
            <ng-template  #nzTreeTemplate let-node>
                
              <ng-container *ngIf="node.isLeaf">                          
                    <nz-select  nzMode="multiple" [(ngModel)]="listOfSelectedValue">
                    </nz-select>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngIf="!node.isLeaf">
                <nz-checkbox [(ngModel)]="node.checked">{{ node.title }}</nz-checkbox>
              </ng-container>
  
            </ng-template>
        </nz-tree>
</nz-tabset>
```

- Component:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NzTreeComponent } from 'ng-zorro-antd/tree';
import { objectModel, objectModel2 } from './select-informations-request.metadata';

@Component({
  selector: 'tree',
  templateUrl: './tree.component.html'
})
export class SelectInformationsRequestComponent
{
  objectModel2: any = objectModel2;

  @ViewChild('nzTreeComponent', { static: false }) nzTreeComponent!: NzTreeComponent;

  listOfSelectedValue = ['1', '2'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `nzCheckable` from `nz-tree`.

Here is a working snippet, slightly modified:

```
  <nz-tree [nzData]="objectModel2">
    <ng-template #nzTreeTemplate let-node>
      <ng-container *ngIf="node.isLeaf">
        <nz-select style="width: 200px" nzMode="multiple" [(ngModel)]="listOfSelectedValue">
          <nz-option nzValue="1" nzLabel="1"></nz-option>
        </nz-select>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="!node.isLeaf">
        <nz-checkbox [(ngModel)]="node.checked">{{ node.title }}</nz-checkbox>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
  </nz-tree>
```

And since you are no longer using the checkbox, you can replace

```
<nz-checkbox [(ngModel)]="node.checked">{{ node.title }}</nz-checkbox>
```

with

```
<span>{{ node.title }}</span>
```

Comment: It renders the dropdowns instead of the checkbox but I have this weird error:
'No value accessor for form control unspecified name attribute'

Comment: It's because you are still trying to initialize a checkbox when you have set `nzCheckbox` to `false`. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, I marked your answer as correct. Also one last question, I have the following scenario: the head is a normal checkbox with 5 leaves. 3 of these leaves are normal checkboxes, 2 are dropdowns. I need to not render the checkboxes for those 2 leaves where there is a dropdown, but to render the checkboxes for the other 3. Also when I check the header checkbox, those 3 leaves which are normal checkboxes should also be checked, as is the normal behavior for the nz-tree. Is there a way to do this or it cannot be done ? I tried a few implementations and I always get the previous error.

Comment: YOu need to use it on a label element not <nz-checkbox>: <label nz-checkbox [(ngModel)]="node.checked">{{ node.title }}</label>